# Usability for I/O and handling of large data sets

Tags: haxe, cross-language, number-crunching

I am trying to figure out what to use for a project (fully free & open source) that will make certain legacy data more accessible to other programmers. I'll try to not go into details, but the data sets contain large amounts of floating-point (32 bits) arrays and also various forms of accompanying data.

My idea is to deliver several libs/DLLs ... etc with their interfaces, for anyone who would program in C++, Java, Python and C# and maybe even other languages. I have coded most programming languages with a 'C' in it myself.

My search led me to Haxe, which I find a very interesting approach. But ... I find it hard to evaluate the usefulness of Haxe for such an undertaking.

Does anybody have any experience with producing number-crunching, data-slicing, technical software layers and whether Haxe would actually deliver nice, usable interfaces for the named languages?

I have tried to get some answers by doing it but the learning curve is pretty steep. Have yet to find how to generate the C++ header files and accompanying libs. Let alone all the software engineering bits, like what dependencies will these libs have?